# New read_only + default behaviour of drf 3.8 gives error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here is an example of the error:

model:

```
from django.db import models

class Hero(models.Model):
    alias = models.(max_length=60)
    character = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

serializer:

```
class HeroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    character = HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, default=<some user object>)
    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('character', 'alias')
```

Viewset:

```
class HeroViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin,
                         mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                         viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Hero.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HeroSerializer
```

Test:

```
def test_created_successfully(self):
    alias = 'blab blah'
    response = self.client.post(self.url, {'name': name})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.data)
```

Now this test used to pass is drf 3.7.7

As I upgraded to drf 3.8.2 this error started to occur:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "character_id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (blah_blah, null).

They said that now default + read_only fields are excluded from writable fields so you have to explicitly save those fields by writing `perform_create` or overriding create, update and save functions of serializer.

So I wrote this in the viewset:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(character=<some user object>)
```

For reference this `perform_create` is called inside create method of `mixins.CreateModelMixin`.

```
   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

so it worked here but now if the same serializer is changed to(character field is changed to name and name has source to "character field".

```
class HeroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = HyperlinkedRelatedField(source='character', read_only=True, default=<some user object>)
    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('name', 'alias')
```

my test fails with

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.data)
AssertionError: 400 != 201 : {'character': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', 
code='required')]}
```

and this test is failing in below line of create function, i.e this is not even reaching the perform_create that i overrote.

```
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Data is invalid.

need help.